# Laravel - Instantiate object and keep it within all controller's methods

Tags: laravel, object, constructor, controller

I'm working with this case where I need to instantiate an object after a form is submitted in a controller. Everything's working fine until I call this object (as a property) from another method. It appears to be null.

If I intentiate the object from constructor method, I have no problem at all.

I can't keep this object in session because of closure.

Here's what i got so far.

// Version with the object iniate within the constructor that's working

```
class SearchConsoleController extends Controller
{
   private $console;

   protected function __construct() {
     $callback = route('searchconsole.callback') ;
     $this->console = $this->setConsole(env('CLIENT_ID'), env('CLIENT_SECRET'), $callback);
   }

   private function setConsole($cliendId, $cliendSecret, $callback){
     $console = new Console(new Google_Client(), $cliendId, $cliendSecret, $callback);
     return $console;
   }

   public function index(Request $request) {
     return view('searchconsole.index')->with('authUrl', $this->console->getAuthUrl());
   }

   public function callback(Request $request){
      if ($request->has('code')) {
         $this->console->acceptCode($request->get('code'));
         return redirect()->action('SearchConsoleController@listSites', [$request]);
      }
      else{
         die('error');
      }
    }
```

Now the version which i'm stucked wih

```
class SearchConsoleController extends Controller
{
   private $console;
   private $callback;

   protected function __construct() {
     $this->callback = route('searchconsole.callback') ;
   }

   private function setConsole($cliendId, $cliendSecret, $callback){
     $console = new Console(new Google_Client(), $cliendId, $cliendSecret, $this->callback);
     return $console;
   }

   public function index(Request $request) {
     // VIEW WITH A FORM FROM WHICH I GET CLIENT_SECRET & CLIENT_ID var

     return view('searchconsole.index');
   }

   public function getAuthUrl(Request $request) {
      // FORM FROM INDEX IS SUBMITTED
      $clientId = ($request->has('google-client-id'))  ? 
          $request->get('google-client-id') : 
          null
      ;
    
      $clientSecret = ($request->has('google-client-secret'))  ? 
          $request->get('google-client-secret') : 
          null
      ;

    $this->console = $this->setConsole($clientId, $clientSecret, $this->callback);
    return $this->console->getAuthUrl();
   }

   public function callback(Request $request){
      if ($request->has('code')) {
         //    ***** MY PROBLEM *********
         $this->console->acceptCode($request->get('code')); // HERE $this->console IS NULL;
         //    *******************
         return redirect()->action('SearchConsoleController@listSites', [$request]);
      }
      else{
         die('error');
      }
    }
```

I just can't figure out how I can do this so console is still available

**UPDATE :**

following @iamab.in advice, i looked into Service Provider but i just dont know how i can instante the Console Object within the service provider.

Here's what i've done.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Helpers\Console;
use Google_Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   /**
    * Register any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(Console::class, function() {
           $request = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
    
           $clientId = ($request->has('google-client-id'))  ? 
             $request->get('google-client-id') : 
             null
           ;
           $clientSecret = ($request->has('google-client-secret'))  ? 
            $request->get('google-client-secret') : 
             null
           ;
           $callback = Route::get()->name('searchconsole.callback');
           return new Console(new Google_Client(), $clientId, $clientSecret, $callback);
         });
    }

  public function boot(){}
  ....
```

I just dont know how and where to implement it.

Thanks again

Update#2 :

okay my solution was working, I just didnt launch the correct app .....

Comment: I guess you could use laravel's singleton binding. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-a-singleton) doc. You may instantiate the `Google_Client` object or `Console` object which is applicable.

Comment: Can try right now but looks like this is what I was looking for! Thanks! Will take a look asap

Comment: @iamab.in : can you please post your anwser so I can mark it as the correct answer? thanks again man, you saved my @$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good idea about the singleton binding thing. The comment was only based on a guess. Better someone with more knowledge adds an answer or I will post an answer after some reading.